# How many arrangements can the seven people sit given they can't sit down next to anyone they sat next to previously?

Tags: combinatorics

> When seven people go out for dinner the first time, they sit as shown in the left figure. When the same seven people go out for dinner the following time, they agree that non one will sit next to a person whom they sat next to the previous time. Bob and Ed sit down first, as shown in the right figure. In how many different arrangements can the other people now sit?

> [image]

---

So I'm not sure exactly how to approach this. I tried casework, but can't seem to find a way that guarantees that I found all arrangements. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is $\boxed{4}$ by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: There is only one person who can sit between Bob and Ed; who it it? Once that person is seated, there are only two people who can sit next to Bob on his other side, and there are only two people who can sit next to Ed on *his* other side, and it turns out, conveniently, that those choices can be made independently. After that you’ll have just two people left to seat.